# Java - fire event when any property of object changes

Tags: java

In Java, what is the most elegant way for an object to fire an event whenever any property of an object changes?

My domain model has several objects like

```
class MyClass {

    String id;
    String name;
    Collection<MyThing> mythings= new HashSet<MyThing>();
    // more fields...
    Date lastUpdated;

    //constructor, getters and setters, etc
}
```

I need lastUpdated to be set to "today" whenever any of the properties (id/name/mythings) changes.

I would prefer a solution that is not JDO-specific, and definitely don't want this logic in the datastore (auto-timestamp column in the RDBMS etc).

I could put

```
this.lastUpdated = new Date();
```

in every setter, or fire a custom event in every setter, but that's ugly and error-prone.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: FYI, this sounds exactly like what Java beans are, you might want to look into them.

Comment: AOP requires an interface, unless you're going to do byte code enhancement.  I don't typically use interfaces for model objects.  I wouldn't recommend AOP for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `PropertyChangeListener` interface and register your interest on the part of clients.  It's been part of the Java Bean specification since 1.0.

They aren't all about UI elements.  They were conceived as a way to match VB-like features for IDEs (e.g the Bean Factory).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html

Comment: I came across that. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html#bound  - looking at the examples it seems like I'd still have to firePropertyChange in the setter for every property I want this behavior on?

Comment: How else would you expect to have it happen?

Comment: I was hoping there was an automatic "onUpdated" event buried somewhere that I could use, or a class with that functionality that I could extend. Your answer seems to be "as good as it gets"; thanks!

Comment: @MT1: that would require some spiffy inheritance and dynamic rewriting of the property setters on the fly.

Comment: I'm not sure this comment is helpful seven years after the original question.